# How to execute multiple queries in same time using o.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, odata

I'm using the **o.js** library from npm : https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata

So first I'm connecting successfully , no issue here :

```
 const oHandler = o(byDUrl, {

        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64encodedData
        }
    });
```

**My goal** : Execute multiple queries in same time and once they're all done handle the result :

```
Promise.all([oHandler.get("CostCentreCollection").query({
            "$top" : parseInt(99999),
            "$format": 'json'
        }),
        oHandler.get("ServiceProductCollection").query({
            "$top" : parseInt(99999),
            "$format": 'json'
        }),
        oHandler.get("JobNameCollection").query({
            "$top" : parseInt(99999),
            "$format": 'json'
        }),
        oHandler.get("CompanyCurrentNameCollection").query({
            "$top" : parseInt(99999),
            "$format": 'json'
        }),
        ]).then(results => {
            console.timeEnd("Fetching Counts");
            console.log(results);
        }).catch(console.log);
    }
```

The query is working without an error but the issue is within the "weird" result :

I'm expecting a result that looks something like :

```
 [
    { d: [Object] },
    { d: [Object] },
    { d: [Object] },
    { d: [Object] }
  ]
```

But instead my output is like this, am I doing something wrong or it's a normal behavior ? Why I am getting 4 times the same results in the array?  :

```
[
  { d: { results: [Array] } },
  [
    { d: [Object] },
    { d: [Object] },
    { d: [Object] },
    { d: [Object] }
  ],
  [
    { d: [Object] },
    { d: [Object] },
    { d: [Object] },
    { d: [Object] }
  ],
  [
    { d: [Object] },
    { d: [Object] },
    { d: [Object] },
    { d: [Object] }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promise.all() receives an array of promises and resolves to an array of values returned by each promise passed to it, and in the same order as the promises.

Since your query promises each return an array, the final result is an array of arrays.

You can use `Array#flat()` or spread `[...results]` to merge them.

Basic example:

```js
const getData = (i) => Promise.resolve(Array(3).fill(i))

Promise.all([getData(1), getData(2), getData(3)])
  .then(res => {
    console.log('results:', JSON.stringify(res))
    return res.flat()
  }).then(flattened => {
    console.log('results flattened:', JSON.stringify(flattened))
  })
```